# Looking up 2nd value in a list based on a user input if first value

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of lists (dictionary_list), here are 3 sample lists:

```
{'_chk2m': 'Name1@domain.com', '_cn6ca': 'PaulDu', '_cokwr': '005C0000003yL', '_ckd7g': 'Sourcing', '_cre1l': u'Paul Dumond \xa0', '_cpzh4': 'Name1@domain.com', '_ciyn3': 'abc'}
{'_chk2m': 'Name2@domain.com', '_cn6ca': 'Jeanell', '_cokwr': '005C0000003we', '_ckd7g': 'Tech Sourcer Team', '_cre1l': u'Jeanelle Gourley \xa0', '_cpzh4': 'Name2@domain.com', '_ciyn3': 'bcd'}
{'_chk2m': 'Name3@domain.com', '_cn6ca': 'Twanna', '_cokwr': '005C0000004tB', '_ckd7g': 'Tech Sourcer Team', '_cre1l': u'Twanna Lippincott \xa0', '_cpzh4': 'Name3@domain.com', '_ciyn3': 'def'}
```

I'd like to ask the user for a name and have the script find the list of data with that name, then return to me the email address.

Here is a bit of code I have so far:

```
def Lookup(in_path):
    # read file into memory
    file_obj = open(in_path, 'rb')
    reader = csv.reader(file_obj, delimiter='\t')
    data = []

    # create a raw_input here?    

    for row in reader:
        if any('raw_input_here' in elt for elt in row):
            # something to grab/store the email address here
    file_obj.close()

    print 'Found', "Joe Smith's", 'email.'
    conf = raw_input('save this email? (Y|N): ').upper()[0]

    if conf == 'Y':
        # write data to file
        file_obj = open(in_path, 'wb')
        writer = csv.writer(file_obj)
        writer.writerows(data)
        file_obj.close()
```

I'm not sure about how to ask the user for a raw input that looks up the right list of data (based on given name), and I'm also unsure how to return the email (possibly return different list index once that list is located?)

Comment: What was the question?  Which part is giving you trouble?

Comment: I'm stuck on how to make a raw input that looks for whatever list the user's given name is in, and also how to then look at a different index in that list to return the email.

Comment: It looks like you are searching through a file looking for the line that contains the name that the user entered, printing the email address in that line.  Is the data you showed us three lines of the file?  If so that looks like json formatted data.

Comment: The data is directly read from a spreadsheet that has one user's info per row, and I am attempting to create functionality that looks up one column of info (email) based on the user input (name)

Comment: Each example is its own row, so these are 3 example rows. If I am able to convert these to dicts, I'm still not sure how I might be able to look up an email from a name... I thought it was only possible to look up a value by its Key, so that my goal of using one entry to find another wouldn't apply

Comment: dict.values() will return a list with all the values in the dictionary, so ... ```if name in d.values()```.  Then when you find it, email = d['_chk2m'].

Comment: so use the json module to convert to dict then use [dict.values()](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eval() function seems to be able to turn those lines into dictionaries.  There are a lot of cautions and warnings *out there* on the net about using eval() - you must be sure that there is **no** malicious content in the string(s) you are evaluating.  I put your three lines of data in a text file and this seems to work.

```
from pprint import pprint

name = 'Jeanell'

with open('test_data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            dictionary = eval(line.rstrip())
            if name in dictionary.values():
                email_address1 = dictionary['_chk2m']
                email_address2 = dictionary['_cpzh4']
                print dictionary['_cre1l'], email_address1, email_address2
                pprint(dictionary)
        except SyntaxError as e:
            # a lone newline character ( '\n') at the end of the file
            # is causing this
            print
            print e
```

The output is:

```
>>> 
Jeanelle Gourley  Name2@domain.com Name2@domain.com
{'_chk2m': 'Name2@domain.com',
 '_ciyn3': 'bcd',
 '_ckd7g': 'Tech Sourcer Team',
 '_cn6ca': 'Jeanell',
 '_cokwr': '005C0000003we',
 '_cpzh4': 'Name2@domain.com',
 '_cre1l': u'Jeanelle Gourley \xa0'}

unexpected EOF while parsing (<string>, line 0)
>>>
```